# How to display the user input in a panel

Tags: c++, panel, ncurses

I am actually coding an editor in console, something like nano. 
For getting user input , I placed a window inside a panel, and use the function mvwprintw to asking the user input. After lot of tests , I am sure that the input is getting, but it is not displaying while the user is typing . 
Does someone has an idea to solve this problem ? 
thanks.

```
void keybord::init_panel_window()

{   

//prepare the window     

int x, y, i;

bool show_it=true;

char label[1000];

y = 2;

x = 10;

my_wins = newwin(10, 40, y, x);

 field[0] = new_field(1, 10, y, x, 0, 0);

 field[1] = NULL;

   field[2] = NULL;

 //char user_input[1000];

//attach panel to window and put this panel on top
my_panels = new_panel(my_wins); 
set_panel_userptr(my_panels, &show_it);
update_panels();
doupdate();

sprintf(label, " enter your message ");
//show the window by printing box arround window 
int startx, starty, height, width;
getbegyx(my_wins, starty, startx);
getmaxyx(my_wins, height, width);
box(my_wins, 0, 0);
mvwaddch(my_wins, 2, 0, ACS_LTEE); 
mvwhline(my_wins, 2, 1, ACS_HLINE, width - 2); 
mvwaddch(my_wins, 2, width - 1, ACS_RTEE); 
print_in_middle(my_wins, 1, 0, width, label, COLOR_PAIR(2));  
//show_panel(my_panels);       
}`


  void keybord::print_in_middle(WINDOW *win, int starty, int startx, int    width, char *string, chtype color)
  {       int length, x, y;
      float temp;
      char user_input[100];


    show_panel(my_panels); //show the panel 

    if(win == NULL)
            win = stdscr;
    getyx(win, y, x);
    if(startx != 0)
            x = startx;
    if(starty != 0)
            y = starty;
    if(width == 0)
            width = 80;

    length = strlen(string);
    temp = (width - length)/ 2;
    x = startx + (int)temp;

   // mvwprintw(win, y, x, " %s", string);
    mvwscanw(win,y+5,x+4,"%s",user_input); //USER INPUT , IT'S WORKINK BUT THE INPUT IS NOT DISPLAYING WHILE THE USER IS TYPING 
    refresh();
    printw("value : %s************************* ",user_input );
      wattron(win, color);
     mvwprintw(win, y, x, " %s", user_input);
    refresh();
    wattroff(win, color);
   // hide_panel(my_panels);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your complete program is not shown, but a simple/likely explanation is that in the initialization it calls `noecho()`, and the standard screen `stdscr` is used, e.g., by passing a NULL as the first parameter of `keybord::print_in_middle()`.

If `echo()` is enabled for the `win` parameter of `keybord::print_in_middle()`, then it will behave as you intended.

Comment: It's working now .Thanks very much . I did not understand this point about the library :)